# IS there a way to only lock the fields in MS Access and allow users to edit the data?

Tags: database, properties, locking

we are several people using MS Access on Shared Drive editing Data. I have noticed people changing the field properties. Is there a way I can lock the Fields and allow users to edit only the data?